# importing a matrix consists of both strings and numerical values

Tags: r

When reading a csv file, where each cell can be strings or numerical values. Which approach should I use to read this csv file into a matrix. The tricky thing is that I may need to perform some computation on this imported matrix. If an entry is a string, I need to perform some character-based operation on this string, e.g., comparing it with another string. If an entry is an numerical value, I need to perform a add/subtract operation on it.  How should I import this csv file:

```
testmatrix = as.character(read.csv("test.csv", sep=","))
testmatrix = as.vector(read.csv("test.csv", sep=","))
```

The data is like this

```
word1   word2   123  word3
234     456     word4  word5
```

Comment: your two lines look identical to me! Also, you will be reading the cvs file into R as a `data.frame` rather than a matrix with this approach.  `Data.frames` are lists of single typed vectors, you can then convert your data to a matrix if you like, but then the data must all be a single type.  It sounds like for each calulation/comparison you do, you will need to do something like `if(!is.na(as.numeric(x))) do something`

Comment: Could you add an example of your data too ?

Comment: I have shown an example of the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read into a dataframe with one of the `read.*` functions but since there are no commas, `read.csv` doesn't make much sense. Be sure to use 'stringsAsFactors' to avoid automatic factor creation. Convert to matrix to facilitate processing with vectorized functions like `sum`:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="word1   word2   123  word3
 234     456     word4  word5", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 mdat <- data.matrix(dat)  # you get warning but it's safe to ignore them in this case.
 sum(as.numeric(mdat)[ is.numeric(mdat) ] )
#[1] NA  left in to illustrate need to use na.rm=TRUE
 sum(as.numeric(mdat)[ is.numeric(mdat) ] , na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 813   expected result
```